# Are all dipeptides synthesizable?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins

Probably a basic question, but are all possible dipeptides synthesizable?
For 20 amino acids, there should be in principle 190 dipeptides; do they
all exist or is there chemistry that makes some combinations unstable?
A straight forward generalization would be to ask what percentage of
peptides (or proteins) are synthesizable (in the lab or in cells).

Comment: Yes, all dipeptides can be synthesized - it's simply connecting the carboxyl group of the first amino acid to the primary amine of the second amino acid. No big deal. The second part of your question does not make sense - what do you mean? Given a supply of amino acids, a cell can synthesize any protein in its genome. There are limitations of polypeptide synthesis in the lab which increase as the peptide chain grows. There is a large body of literature on this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any peptide can be synthesized in a lab. Length is probably limited by yield, but I imagine that can be overcome by, say, ligating or elongating previously synthesized peptides.

Comment: @MattDMo, I'm asking the question without necessarily  referening to genomes or what happens in the cell. As an abstract alphabet of 20 letters you can create a huge number of combinations of words of length N; translating the letters to amino acids and the words to peptides, how many of these words are synthesizable? It seems your answer for N=2 is 100%. For larger N I can't imagine this to be true,  or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @secretlyfamous You mention cells in your question, which is why I brought them up. In cells, *N* can be quite large, well over 34,000 in the case of the muscle protein [titin](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8WZ42#sequences). As I mentioned in my previous comment, there is a large body of literature on the capabilities and limitations of chemical polypeptide synthesis, with yield inversely proportional to length. A quick Google search yielded [this page](http://www.lifetein.com/long_peptide_synthesis.html), which describes the synthesis of 169 AA by the ligation of several shorter precursors.

Comment: @canadianer I highly doubt titin could be synthesized in the lab, though with a good deal of work a lot of (much) smaller proteins probably could. *N* is not infinite, though. I know antibodies can't be chemically synthesized (two 50 kDa chains and two 25 kDa ones for IgG). Plus, post-translational modifications like disulfide bonds could present a lot of problems.

Comment: @secretlyfamous If your interests are entirely in the realm of chemical peptide synthesis, you may find a lot more experience at [chemistry.se] than here. While biochemistry is on-topic here, this question seems to have a lot more *chemistry* than *bio*.

Comment: @MattDMo, thanks for the clarification. My interest is mainly in the statistics. The actual mechanism is far too complex for me to pursue. I wasn't sure about which tags to use; plus it looks like some of my tags were editted out.

Comment: @MattDMo I really don't know anything about it, though I did say peptide and not protein. Is it impossible to synthesize antibodies or just not practical?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing magical or mysterious about a peptide bond.

Comment: @canadianer Yields drop off very quickly above 20 - 30 amino acids, with bad products making up more of the mix. Disulfides are a pain, but there are ways to control them [using protecting groups](http://ir.uiowa.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3450&context=etd). The nice thing about peptide synthesis is being able to use a huge variety of amino acids, which has allowed some [neat stuff](http://www.cell.com/cell/abstract/S0092-8674%2815%2900636-4?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0092867415006364%3Fshowall%3Dtrue&cc=y=).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason why not. Just to make sure, I decided to test. I ran a search on all human proteins (using the UniProt flat file) for all possible dipeptide combinations of the 20 standard amino acids (selenocysteine is also present in humans but only in 22--or so, depending on how you count them--proteins, so I wouldn't expect all possible sec-containing dipeptides to be present) .

As expected, each of the 400 possible dipeptides were indeed present in at least one human protein. In case anyone wants to repeat this, the "protocol" is as follows:

1. Download the human flat file from [Expassy](ftp://ftp.expasy.org/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/taxonomic_divisions/uniprot_sprot_human.dat.gz).
2. Extract the peptide sequences

   ```
   perl -ne 'if(s/^\s+//){s/\s+//g;print}' human.flat > human.pep
   ```
3. Generate the list of possible dipeptides:

   ```
   AA
   AC
   AD
   AE
   AF
   AG
   AH
   AI
   AK
   AL
   AM
   AN
   AP
   AQ
   AR
   AS
   AT
   AV
   AW
   AY
   CA
   CC
   CD
   CE
   CF
   CG
   CH
   CI
   CK
   CL
   CM
   CN
   CP
   CQ
   CR
   CS
   CT
   CV
   CW
   CY
   DA
   DC
   DD
   DE
   DF
   DG
   DH
   DI
   DK
   DL
   DM
   DN
   DP
   DQ
   DR
   DS
   DT
   DV
   DW
   DY
   EA
   EC
   ED
   EE
   EF
   EG
   EH
   EI
   EK
   EL
   EM
   EN
   EP
   EQ
   ER
   ES
   ET
   EV
   EW
   EY
   FA
   FC
   FD
   FE
   FF
   FG
   FH
   FI
   FK
   FL
   FM
   FN
   FP
   FQ
   FR
   FS
   FT
   FV
   FW
   FY
   GA
   GC
   GD
   GE
   GF
   GG
   GH
   GI
   GK
   GL
   GM
   GN
   GP
   GQ
   GR
   GS
   GT
   GV
   GW
   GY
   HA
   HC
   HD
   HE
   HF
   HG
   HH
   HI
   HK
   HL
   HM
   HN
   HP
   HQ
   HR
   HS
   HT
   HV
   HW
   HY
   IA
   IC
   ID
   IE
   IF
   IG
   IH
   II
   IK
   IL
   IM
   IN
   IP
   IQ
   IR
   IS
   IT
   IV
   IW
   IY
   KA
   KC
   KD
   KE
   KF
   KG
   KH
   KI
   KK
   KL
   KM
   KN
   KP
   KQ
   KR
   KS
   KT
   KV
   KW
   KY
   LA
   LC
   LD
   LE
   LF
   LG
   LH
   LI
   LK
   LL
   LM
   LN
   LP
   LQ
   LR
   LS
   LT
   LV
   LW
   LY
   MA
   MC
   MD
   ME
   MF
   MG
   MH
   MI
   MK
   ML
   MM
   MN
   MP
   MQ
   MR
   MS
   MT
   MV
   MW
   MY
   NA
   NC
   ND
   NE
   NF
   NG
   NH
   NI
   NK
   NL
   NM
   NN
   NP
   NQ
   NR
   NS
   NT
   NV
   NW
   NY
   PA
   PC
   PD
   PE
   PF
   PG
   PH
   PI
   PK
   PL
   PM
   PN
   PP
   PQ
   PR
   PS
   PT
   PV
   PW
   PY
   QA
   QC
   QD
   QE
   QF
   QG
   QH
   QI
   QK
   QL
   QM
   QN
   QP
   QQ
   QR
   QS
   QT
   QV
   QW
   QY
   RA
   RC
   RD
   RE
   RF
   RG
   RH
   RI
   RK
   RL
   RM
   RN
   RP
   RQ
   RR
   RS
   RT
   RV
   RW
   RY
   SA
   SC
   SD
   SE
   SF
   SG
   SH
   SI
   SK
   SL
   SM
   SN
   SP
   SQ
   SR
   SS
   ST
   SV
   SW
   SY
   TA
   TC
   TD
   TE
   TF
   TG
   TH
   TI
   TK
   TL
   TM
   TN
   TP
   TQ
   TR
   TS
   TT
   TV
   TW
   TY
   VA
   VC
   VD
   VE
   VF
   VG
   VH
   VI
   VK
   VL
   VM
   VN
   VP
   VQ
   VR
   VS
   VT
   VV
   VW
   VY
   WA
   WC
   WD
   WE
   WF
   WG
   WH
   WI
   WK
   WL
   WM
   WN
   WP
   WQ
   WR
   WS
   WT
   WV
   WW
   WY
   YA
   YC
   YD
   YE
   YF
   YG
   YH
   YI
   YK
   YL
   YM
   YN
   YP
   YQ
   YR
   YS
   YT
   YV
   YW
   YY
   ```

   Save that list as `dip.txt`.
4. Use that file to search the protein sequences:

   ```
   perl -ne 'BEGIN{open(A,"human.pep"); while(<A>){chomp; $k.=$_}}; chomp; print "$_\n" if $k=~/$_/  ' dip.txt
   ```

The script above will print each dipeptide that was found in at least one protein. Since all were printed, all dipeptides exist in the human proteome.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Your answer looks at things from a slightly
different angle (dipeptide occurrence in proteins) which is actually a more interesting
angle. I asked a simplified question about dipeptide occurrence on their own first;
the answer to that seems to be yes. I am also in fact interested in the case for larger
N and the statistics of their occurrence in proteins. I'll take a shot at modifying your
script to do some more searches. BTW, you caught a mistake in the number of possible
combinations of dipeptides, it is in fact 400 and not 190 as I put in the question.

Comment: Yeah, a negative result wouldn't have been conclusive but a positive one is. My assumption was that if a dipeptide occurs in a protein, it can be synthesized. You seem to be suggesting that the dipeptide alone might not be stable and could need the rest of the peptide in order to be so. That's quite interesting and may well be the case but my structural chemistry knowledge is pitiful so I won't venture an opinion on it. As for larger Ns, my script won't help you much. It's a very simplistic approach.